# IE11 ignores font-size inherit in compability mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

Consider this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>CSS test</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            h4 {
                font-size: 1.4em;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: inherit;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h4>The first header</h4>
            <p>Some text...</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4 class="title">The second header</h4>
            <p>Some more text2...</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running this in IE11 (or any other modern browser) will render the second header in the same size as the paragraph text, because of "font-size: inherit" that is applied to the "title" class.

However, if I run the same code in IE11 in compability mode, the second header is rendered in the same size as the first header. "font-size: inherit" seems to be ignored.

Why does IE11 behave like this in compability mode? Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compatibility View is an emulation of IE7, which does not support the `inherit` keyword (with a few obscure exceptions). Proper support for `inherit` was only introduced in IE8, and to ensure the accuracy of IE7 emulation, this full support is not made available in Compatibility View.

So yes, this is expected behavior.